# Grouped rebased price in DAX

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I am working on historical prices data from Yahoo and I would like to create a dynamic rebased price chart in Excel. Hence, I chose to use power pivot and DAX.
I have 3 tables that have the following structure :

- price_data with the following columns = Index, Date, ISIN, Symbols, Adj Close
- Listed_Comps with the following columns = ISIN, Company Name, Sectors
- calendar which is a date table

The central table is price_data, and it's linked with companies on ISIN.

I have identified several steps to create my chart:

1. Get the dates for which we want to have our rebased price:

```
StartDate :=
CALCULATE (
    MIN ( 'Calendar'[Date] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( price_data, 'Calendar'[Date] )
)
```

It outputs the minimum date selected by my timeline slicer.

```
MinimumAvailableDate :=
CALCULATE (
    MIN ( price_data[Date] ),
    ALLEXCEPT (
        price_data,
        price_data[ISIN],
        price_data[Symbols],
        Listed_Comps[Company name],
        Listed_Comps[ISIN CODE],
        Listed_Comps[Sector]
    )
)
```

It outputs the minimum date that can be found for a company or a sector.

```
MinDate :=
CALCULATE (
    MIN ( price_data[Date] ),
    ALLEXCEPT (
        price_data,
        price_data[ISIN],
        price_data[Symbols],
        Listed_Comps[ISIN CODE],
        Listed_Comps[Ticker],
        Listed_Comps[Company name],
        Listed_Comps[Sector]
    ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( price_data[Date] ), 'price_data'[Date] >= [StartDate] )
)
```

It outputs the first date above StartDate for a company or a sector. I use it to determine the Beginning price to rebase my data.

2. Get the average prices

```
AverageClosePrice :=
VAR MinimumAvailableDate = [MinimumAvailableDate]
VAR StartDate = [StartDate]
RETURN
    IF (
        MinimumAvailableDate <= StartDate,
        AVERAGE ( price_data[Adj Close] ),
        BLANK ()
    )
```

It's a measure to only get Close Price if the Company has data points on the whole period looked at to prevent anomalies.

```
TickerStartAverageClosePrice :=
CALCULATE (
    [Average of Adj Close],
    ALLEXCEPT (
        price_data,
        price_data[Symbols],
        price_data[ISIN],
        Listed_Comps[ISIN CODE],
        Listed_Comps[Company name],
        Listed_Comps[Sector],
        price_data[Sector]
    ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( price_data[Index] ), price_data[Index] = [MinId] )
)
```

It's the beginning price to calculate rebased price for a given ticker.

And finally:

```
RebasedPrice :=
[AverageClosePrice] / [TickerStartAverageClosePrice]
```

The issue is that my code only works for individual companies. I would like to be able to look at groups of companies and there price evolutions. As such, i believe that i should get an the sum of average prices for groups. I tried creating the following measure:

```
Test :=
VAR MinimumAvailableDate = [MinimumAvailableDate]
VAR StartDate = [StartDate]
VAR TickerSymbol =
    IF (
        HASONEVALUE ( price_data[Symbols] ),
        -- Check if only one ticker is selected
        VALUES ( price_data[Symbols] ),
        BLANK ()
    )
VAR GroupSymbols =
    VALUES ( price_data[Symbols] )
RETURN
    IF (
        MinimumAvailableDate <= StartDate,
        IF (
            NOT ISBLANK ( TickerSymbol ),
            -- Check if TickerSymbol is not blank
            [TickerStartAverageClosePrice],
            SUMX (
                FILTER ( price_data, price_data[Symbols] IN GroupSymbols ),
                [TickerStartAverageClosePrice]
            )
        ),
        BLANK ()
    )
```

I manage to get the sum of AverageClosePrices but individually for each dates whereas I only want the sum of close prices for the start date in this measure.